# how to extract each numbers from pandas string column to list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to do that?

I have pandas dataframe looks like:

```py
Column_A
11.2 some text 17 some text 21
some text 25.2 4.1 some text 53 17 78
121.1 bla bla bla 14 some text
12 some text
```

I need to transfer this each row to separated list:

```py
listA[0] = 11.2 listA[1] = 17 listA[2] = 21
listB[0] = 25.2 listB[1] = 4.1 listB[2] = 53 listB[3] = 17 listB[4] = 78
listC[0] = 121.1 listC[1] = 14
listD[0] = 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` to find all the occurrences of the numbers either integer or float.

```py
df['Column_A'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", x)).tolist()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
[['11.2', '17', '21'], ['25.2', '4.1', '53', '17', '78'], ['121.1', '14'], ['12']]
```

If you want, you can type cast them to `float`/`int` checking if the extracted string has `.` in them, something like this:

```py
df['Column_A'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", x)).map(lambda x: [int(i) if '.' not in i else float(i) for i in x]).tolist()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
[[11.2, 17, 21], [25.2, 4.1, 53, 17, 78], [121.1, 14], [12]]
```

As pointed by @Uts, we can directly call `findall` over `Series.str` as:

```py
listA, listB, listC, listD = df.Column_A.str.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+")
```

Comment: So how to use each list to Seperately? I need to use it Seperated. i mean i need seperated list like ListA, ListB, ListC, ListD

Comment: You can get this output in a list for eg `result` and `result[0]`, `result[1]` ... will give the matched numbers at `first row`, `second row` and so on.... i.e. `result[0]` will give `[11.2, 17, 21]` and `result[0][0]` will give `11.2`

Comment: @ThePyGuy - `apply and to_list` function might not be required. `listA, listB, listC, listD = df.Column_A.str.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+")`

Comment: @Uts, yeah we can actually directly call `findall` over `series.str`

Comment: @Uts, I added that too in the answer, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
[re.findall(r"\d+?\.?\d*", x) for x in Column_A]
```

You'll get a list of lists for every row in that column. It will be strings but you can convert to float however you want after that.